# How to display a tooltip during mouseover on a select Option?

Tags: java, title, tapestry, palette

I'm actually working on a form that include a list box with Select options (using Tapestry 3.58).

In the tml file, the select box is build as followed:

```
<t:select t:id="selectPo" t:value="selectPo" model="poSelectModel" encoder="encoderPo" id="selectPo"/>
```

in the Java File, i have a setUpRender as the following

```
@Property
private SelectModel poSelectModel;

@Inject
SelectModelFactory selectModelFactory;

public void setupRender() {
    poSelectModel = selectModelFactory.create(listePo, "label"); 
}
```

on a mouseover event, Is ist possible to display a tooltip with entire value of label if this label is too long to be displayed in the list box?

Thanks.

Comment: Just so you know, JavaScript is NOT Java.

Comment: I found the solution of my problem in this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550859/how-to-display-tooltip-title-of-option-text-in-tapestry-5-3-6-palette-componen